# How to show AdMob ads aligned to the right of the screen on Device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am trying to align Admob banner to right of the device screen. However It is not working for me. I am creating a banner like this

```
  RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(activity);
                activity.addContentView(layout, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                setLayout(layout, llType);
```

Here `setLayout` is called which set the layout of the banner depending upon the type

```
   private void setLayout(RelativeLayout layout, int type) {
    switch (type) {
        case AdLayoutType.Top:
            layout.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            break;
        case AdLayoutType.Bottom:
            layout.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            break;
        case AdLayoutType.Left:
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams leftParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            leftParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
            layout.setLayoutParams(leftParams);
             break;
        case AdLayoutType.Right:
//This does not work as it gives Class cast exception
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rightParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                rightParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
                layout.setLayoutParams(rightParams);
             break;
            default:
                break;
        }
```

Can somebody help me in this?
Thanks
    }

Comment: missed the **break;** after _AdLayoutType.Left:_ block by intent?

Comment: Thanks, that was not intentional, but same issue.

Answer (score 1):

well I think I know whats the problem.

The outer layout of your Activity is always a FrameLayout. Cause youre adding the RelativLayout to the Activity layout the parent is FrameLayout not RelativeLayout this is why there is a class cast Exception. FrameLayout.LayoutParams expected.

Here the example in xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal">
    </RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal">
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" <!-- has no effect, default align is left -->
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
<!-- has no effect, cause parent is no RelativeLayout this is causing class cast exception -->
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
</RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Remove comments for working example.

You should have the same exception if you use alignParentBottom insted auf layout_gravity. in the second case.

So to make your code work add either an parent RelativeLayout first, or use only FrameLayout.LayoutParams.

Example (not testet):

```
    private void setLayout(RelativeLayout layout, int type) {
        switch (type) {
            case AdLayoutType.Top:
                layout.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                break;
            case AdLayoutType.Bottom:
                layout.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                break;
            case AdLayoutType.Left:
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams leftParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                layout.setLayoutParams(leftParams);
                layout.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                 break;
            case AdLayoutType.Right:
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams rightParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    layout.setLayoutParams(rightParams);
                    layout.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                 break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
```